# How yield works in Inorder traversal with recursive generator?

Tags: python-3.x, yield

I am learning about recursive generators and found this program on web.

I undertand the recursive version of In-Order traversal but i am having trouble understanding recursive generator.

Specifically i am not able to understand

1. why 'yield x'  is written in for loop?
2. Why 'yield x' is not collected in final list?

I have tried to dubug the generator and added the watch but i found that recursive call execute multiple time 'yield x' and it's not collected in final result.

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, label, left=None, right=None):
        self.label = label
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __repr__(self, level=0, indent="    "):
        s = level*indent + repr(self.label)
        if self.left:
            s = s + "\\n" + self.left.__repr__(level+1, indent)
        if self.right:
            s = s + "\\n" + self.right.__repr__(level+1, indent)
        return s

    def __iter__(self):
        return inorder(self)


def tree(list):
    n = len(list)
    if n == 0:
        return []
    i = n // 2
    return Tree(list[i], tree(list[:i]), tree(list[i + 1:]))





# Recursive Generator
def inorder(t):
    if t:
        for x in inorder(t.left):
            yield x
        yield t.label
        for x in inorder(t.right):
            yield x
```

Role of yield x inside for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for, but perhaps it is something along these lines:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, label, left=None, right=None):
        self.label = label
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __repr__(self, level=0, indent="    "):
        s = level*indent + repr(self.label)
        if self.left:
            s = s + "\n" + self.left.__repr__(level+1, indent)
        if self.right:
            s = s + "\n" + self.right.__repr__(level+1, indent)
        return s

    def __iter__(self):
        return inorder(self)


def tree(list):
    n = len(list)
    if n == 0:
        return []
    i = n // 2
    return Tree(list[i], tree(list[:i]), tree(list[i + 1:]))


def inorder(t):
    if t:
        for x in t.left:
            yield x
        yield t.label
        for x in t.right:
            yield x

t = tree("ABCDEFG")
[print(i.label) for i in t]
```

which outputs:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
```

With that code you could instead:

```
[print('----------\n', i) for i in t]
```

which outputs each hierarchical node in the tree, from A to G.

**Edit:** If you're asking how generator works, perhaps this example could be enlightening:

```
>>> def list2gen(lst):
...     for elem in lst:
...             yield str(elem) + '_'
...
>>> print(list2gen([1,2,'7',-4]))
<generator object list2gen at 0x000001B0DEF8B0C0>
>>> print(list(list2gen([1,2,'7',-4])))
['1_', '2_', '7_', '-4_']
```

If your debugger breaks multiple times at a yield, but those elements never materialize in the resulting generator, you'd have to attribute that to bugs in the debugger. I've not used one for Python in more than a decade; they used to be notoriously bug-infested. In Python the paradigm is "test is king," and "avoid manual debugging," but I disagree with that. (The only reason I don't is lack of *great* IDE's and debuggers.)

Comment: I know program is working correctly.Specifically i am not able to understand

why 'yield x' is written in for loop?
Why 'yield x' is not collected in final list?

Comment: You're yielding `t.label`, so "correctly" seems to be somewhat debatable. There were a couple of other tiny bugs, which I fixed as well, such as `"\\n"` instead of using `"\n"`, etc.

Comment: I forget label there, corrected . why 'yield x' is written in for loop?
Why 'yield x' is not collected in final list?

Comment: I do not understand that question. All nodes of the tree are available in the generator if you iterate through it. Hence `print([i.label for i in t])` will output `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']`. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: No, Program is working perfectly, i wanted to understand working of 'yield x' inside of for loop of left and right node. If you debug the code your pointer will go to ''yield x'  multiple times but those yields are not collected in final list

Comment: Debuggers, for many languages, will have to bind boilerplate code to some/any source line. Even though it really might not belong to any source per se. This used to be very common with gcc/gdb loops (many years ago). I'm guessing this is the case for you as well, where the compiler/debugger places loop boilerplate python byte code on the last line of the loop. If you have a corresponding disassembler you can follow the code. This may be a problem with the compiler, the debugger or both. It's one of the reasons I stopped using debuggers in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you don't understand is how the generator works? The generator is different from the iterator, it is not directly calculating the worthy collection, it is dynamically getting all the values. If the result of `inorder(t.left)` is not traversed by a `for` loop, then `yield inorder(t.left)` will return the entire generator created for `t.left`. Because your entire `inorder` function is a generator.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a specific description document. This is a description based on my experience. Others are welcome to make corrections to my opinion. If someone can provide a specific official description, welcome to add